# LOAD DATA INFILE MySQL(MariaDB)

Tags: csv, mariadb

I am trying to load a .csv file into MariaDB but I am struggling with the query.
Here is how the.csv file is formatted:

```
USER    DATE    TIME    TESTRESULT  ERRORCODE
Esa_Test    16.5.2022   12:36:59    Fail    1(MinMaxError)
Esa_Test    16.5.2022   12:38:02    Fail    1(MinMaxError)
Esa_Test    16.5.2022   12:55:40    Fail    1(MinMaxError)
Esa_Test    17.5.2022   16:15:00    Fail    1(MinMaxError)
DPHYD_Ate   18.5.2022   9:50:11 OK  0(NoError)
```

When I use this query:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\mysql\\data\\test\\log2.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE `test`.`testova2` IGNORE 4 LINES (`USER`, `DATE`, `TIME`, `TESTRESULT`, `ERRORCODE`);
```

The data is loaded successfully but with spaces like this:

```
USER;DATE;TIME;TESTRESULT;ERRORCODE
 E s a _ T e s t ; 1 6 . 5 . 2 0 2 2 ; 1 2 : 3 6 : 5 9 ; F a i l ; 1 ( M i n M a x E r r o r ) 
 E s a _ T e s t ; 1 6 . 5 . 2 0 2 2 ; 1 2 : 3 8 : 0 2 ; F a i l ; 1 ( M i n M a x E r r o r ) 
 E s a _ T e s t ; 1 6 . 5 . 2 0 2 2 ; 1 2 : 5 5 : 4 0 ; F a i l ; 1 ( M i n M a x E r r o r ) 
 E s a _ T e s t ; 1 7 . 5 . 2 0 2 2 ; 1 6 : 1 5 : 0 0 ; F a i l ; 1 ( M i n M a x E r r o r ) 
 D P H Y D _ A t e ; 1 8 . 5 . 2 0 2 2 ; 9 : 5 0 : 1 1 ; O K ; 0 ( N o E r r o r )
```

I tried to define some "limits" via FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '|' in the query but not working. The original file is with encoding UTF16LE according to notepad++
Please help me to build the proper query for my case in order to insert the data correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone looking at this:
I manage to find a solution.
The problem was the encoding.
The solution was to make a short Python script to change the encoding before the upload in MySQL the code is:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("input.csv","r",encoding="utf_16") as fin:
    with codecs.open("output.csv","w",encoding="utf_8") as fout:
        fout.write(fin.read())
```

I automated this and now everything is working.